# Embeded If with awk (filter output content)

Tags: awk, grep, scripting

I am running a few commands on a firewall then splitting up that  log file into multiple smaller files. My data file MASA1 looks like this...

```
MASA1/pri/act# changeto context admin 
MASA1/pri/act/admin# sh run
[removed]
MASA1/pri/act/admin# sh access-list
[removed]
MASA1/pri/act/admin# changeto context Context1
MASA1/pri/act/Context1# sh run
[removed]
MASA1/pri/act/Context1# sh access-list
[removed]
MASA1/pri/act/Context1# changeto context Context2
MASA1/pri/act/Context2# sh run
[removed]
MASA1/pri/act/Context2# sh access-list
[removed]
```

The script below works and will create individual files for every context and every command (i.e. admin_run, admin_acl, Context1_run,...Context2_acl)

```
sed -e '/# sh /{x;p;x};/\<changeto\>/d' MASA1 | awk -v RS=  -F '[ ]|[#/]' '{if ($0~ /sh run/) {f=$1"_"$4"_run"; print > f} else {if ($0~ /sh access-list/) {f=$1"_"$4"_acl"; print > f}}}'
```

However the script will output the whole configuration (sometimes 10000 lines and more). I would like to filter the output by specific IP addresses or object names. Something similar which can be done with

> grep -f filename

Since I am dealing with 20-40 context on the device which will result in 40-80 additional files considering two files per device (_run, _acl).
I would like to build the filter into the script so only those files will be saved where there is hit on the search and only the matching lines not all configuration.

The way how the script works the whole section between two lines started with MASA1 will be considered $0 and as such any additional filtering done as part of the

> if ($0~ /sh run/)

or

> if ($0~ /sh access-list/)

will still result in printing all 10000 lines or so.

It seems that I need to explain my script a bit closer...

```
sed -e '/# sh /{x;p;x};/\<changeto\>/d' MASA1
```

this will modify the data file to eliminate the chnageto lines and create sections separated by extra lines

> ```
> MASA1/pri/act/Context1# sh access-list
> [removed]
>
> MASA1/pri/act/Context2# sh run
> [removed]
>
> MASA1/pri/act/Context2# sh access-list
> [removed]
> ```

The second part ...

```
awk -v RS=  -F '[ ]|[#/]' '{if ($0~ /sh run/) {f=$1"_"$4"_run"; print > f} else {if ($0~ /sh access-list/) {f=$1"_"$4"_acl"; print > f}}}'
```

...will create individual file if the line has the command sh run then the filename will be MASA1_Context1_run or MASA1_Context2_run, if is sh access-list then file name will be MASA1_Context2_acl. The content of the file will be whole [removed] part under the command until the first empty line.

What I would like to do is only create the file is the output is not nil and only output those lines which are a match  with those specific IP addresses instead of the whole [removed] section.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for help with.

Comment: Please at least [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand either, but how far would this get you:

```
awk '/changeto/ {CTX = $NF} /# sh/ {FN = CTX "_" $NF} !/MASA1/ {print > FN}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I think something is not captured correctly or I just missed in my explanation. I edited my original posting to explain it a bit better.

Comment: Not clear either.